# What is a numerical boundary layer?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

An exercise I am working on states;

> Find formally the asymptotic error expansion for the scheme you pro-
> pose in #A3. This will involve two types of terms
> $U = u + h_4 (
> c(x) + Aκ_j + Bκ_{N−j} )$
> where $c(x)$ is a smooth function that solves a BVP and $|κ| < 1$ is a
> root of  $D2κ_j = 0$. The terms involving κ are called numerical boundary
> layers.

I tried searching up the term "numerical boundary layer" and I came up with nothing.

The "A3" portion refers to a modification of finite [difference coeffcients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) to handle skewed finite differences at the boundary.

i.e. this stencil times $h^2$:

$$\frac{11}{12}, \frac{-5}{3}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{-1}{12}$$

will replace the regular 5 point stencil. In general I just don't understand the question.